# Nodejs - Convert a '{a:1}'-style string (generated by `util.format()`) into an objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

`util.format()` generates `'{a:1}'`-style strings which are not valid JSON. (Note that keys are not surrounded by double quotes.) How to convert this kind of strings back into objects?

Answer (score 1):

Use `eval` if it's definitely trustworthy:

```
eval('(' + str + ')');
```

Comment: Oh no, I would try to avoid `eval`.

Comment: @powerboy: Er... why? (Given the additional details, by the way, there is no way you *can* avoid it.)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a very good reason not to, you should be using [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to convert an object to a string and [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to reconstitute an object back from a string.

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` does not handle Regex, Date, Error, etc.

Comment: @powerboy Certainly true.  So what are you ultimately trying to do?  stringify and un-stringify any JavaScript object?

Comment: More specifically, stringify a JS object, send it over the wire, and the client pretty-print it.

Comment: @powerboy Then I think you're stuck with `eval` or developing your own equivalent.